# Burn in issues need help / advice

Tags: android

My screen is an amoled and suffers from constant ghost images they do fade after i continue to use the phone but i fear a permanent burn could happen at any time.

The main problem is i use app like and just let the game run when I'm not using my phone what i was wondering is there a app that i can add a black or white overlay to the game to stop images from ghosting.

Example of what i want is when you receive a text you get a small box comes at the top to reply if i could get a app that does the same but in full screen and in white /black only that would be great. I'm not asking people to code one I'm just asking does something like it already exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind found what I'm looking for

Added the overlay and turn brightness to 0% app runs and looks like screen is off. Should stop the burn ins